# Unable to install fitsne in colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install [fitsne](https://github.com/KlugerLab/pyFIt-SNE) in colab. Recommended way for installation is:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge #if not already in your channels. Needed for fftw.
conda install cython numpy fftw
pip install fitsne
```

Yet, I get following error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fitsne) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fitsne) (0.29.22)
Building wheels for collected packages: fitsne
  Building wheel for fitsne (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fitsne
  Running setup.py clean for fitsne
Failed to build fitsne
Installing collected packages: fitsne
    Running setup.py install for fitsne ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ezkx1s2e/fitsne/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ezkx1s2e/fitsne/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-uzkyz06_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can someone please explain how to fix such an error in colab?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/milesgray/62edda4d868ace7c6b58be9dda251bdc)

```
!git clone https://github.com/KlugerLab/FIt-SNE.git
!wget http://www.fftw.org/fftw-3.3.8.tar.gz
!tar -xf fftw-3.3.8.tar.gz
!cd fftw-3.3.8
!./fftw-3.3.8/configure
!make
!make install
!g++ -std=c++11 -O3  FIt-SNE/src/sptree.cpp FIt-SNE/src/tsne.cpp FIt-SNE/src/nbodyfft.cpp  -o FIt-SNE/bin/fast_tsne -pthread -lfftw3 -lm -Wno-address-of-packed-member
import sys; sys.path.append('FIt-SNE/')
from fast_tsne import fast_tsne
```